# kubectl create namespace with label

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Is there a way to create a namespace with one label using  `kubectl`?

e.g.

```
kubectl create ns <newnamespace> label=appid:foo12
```

as opposed to using `kubectl apply -f <somefile>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right away this is not possible, see `kubectl help create ns` manual.
But there are solutions:
You can either create the namespace with kubectl and label it right away with `kubectl label namespaces <newnamespace> label=appid:foo12` or you could use kubectl to generate the yaml, where you just add the label: `kubectl create namespace demo --dry-run=client -o yaml`

If you are really really eager to have it all in one command, you could modify the JSON inline, for example

```
kubectl create namespace demo --dry-run=client -o yaml | \
 sed  '/^metadata:/a\ \ labels: {"demo":"true"}' | kubectl apply -f -
```

Answer (score 7):

This may help you:

```
kubectl create namespace namespace_name
kubectl label namespaces namespace_name labelname=value --overwrite=true
```

Comment: ++ In fact you can create multiple labels as well as per your use case.
`kubectl label namespaces namespace_name label1=value1 label2=value2 --overwrite=true`

Answer (score 4):

Appreciate it's an old thread but I thought I'd share the one-liner solution I came up with for this:

```
kubectl create namespace foo --dry-run=client -o json|jq '.metadata += {"labels":{"foo":"bar","bar":"foo"}}' | kubectl apply -f -
```

Using the += operator from jq (which I only became aware of today when trying to solve the same problem) to add some arbitrary json for your labels into the dry run output from the create command and then piping to through to kubectl apply.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way yet to set a label while creating the namespace. First, create a namespace and then label it.
Until k8s version " v1.20.15", the labels can be added as below:

```
**Create namespace and add label:**

    kubectl create namespace test
    
    kubectl label namespace test any_name=any_value 
   
    kubectl label namespace test food=delicous
```

More info:

```
kubectl label namespaces -h
```